# In Google Sheets how can I select a list of unique words from a master list of words and display the results in a 5x5 grid?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 25 cells in a 5x5 grid which all currently have the formula:

```
=lookup(randbetween(1,400),'Word list'!$A$1:$B$400)
```

Is there an adjustment to the formula, or code that I can incorporate, which will keep these cells from selecting the same random words?  The needed outcome is a list of 25 unique random words from a master list of words. The words cannot repeat and should be displayed in a 5x5 grid.

Comment: Why not just select the range and randomize?

Comment: Do you need different numbers or different cells? There is a difference if your cells can contain duplicates.

Comment: I need a different random number in each cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer to your question here:
https://support.google.com/docs/thread/11579830?hl=en
which is basically what TheMaster first suggested.

This removes the need for the VLOOKUP.  It takes the whole list of 400 words (in C1:C400) randomly sorts it, and then queries it to pick the first 30 (random) words.
It updates everytime the sheet is changed.
A formula based on that would be:

```
=ArrayFormula( QUERY( 
                  SORT( C1:C400 , 
                    RANDBETWEEN( SIGN( ROW( C1:C400 ) ) , 1E+293 ),
                    1 ) , 
                 "select * WHERE Col1 <> '' limit 30" ) )
```

If your original word list could possibly have duplicates, we can also add a UNIQUE function, before querying, to ensure no duplicates.

Here is a sample sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CA5ALjgxU8tOVqWMTT-CqXqdXl25TlWb73ynVAL61vw/edit?usp=sharing

Let us know if this doesn't achieve what you want.

Edit:  To meet an added requirement, the following formula divides a single column range (A1:A) into a 5 x 5 grid of values/words.  Credit to Maxim Makhrov.
https://sheetswithmaxmakhrov.wordpress.com/2017/12/26/how-to-transpose-every-5-or-n-rows-from-one-column-to-multiple-columns/

```
=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(  
           COLUMN ( OFFSET( INDIRECT("A1") ,,,1,5) )
           + 
          (ROW(  INDIRECT("A1:A" & ROUNDUP( COUNTA(A1:A)/5 ) ) ) - 1) * 5,
        {ROW(A1:A)-ROW(A1)+1,A1:A},
        2,))
```

Comment: This concept seems promising. I do need the results to populate a 5x5 grid of cells. The list of words has no duplicates so UNIQUE is unnecessary.

Comment: Okay, I'm working on it.  So basically, if the formula was in A1, you want it to place 25 random words (from that list) in the grid of 25 cells from A1:E5, correct?

Comment: Okay, updated the sheet to plug the 25 random words into a five by five grid of cells.  Is that achieving what you need?  If so, can you please edit the original question to include this, since that is quite a separate issue from excluding the chance of duplicate words.  Thanks.  As I indicate in the sample, the two formulae could be merged into one, if necessary, but it would be more complex to maintain.

Comment: Works great, nicely done. I will update the question.

Comment: @kirkg13 https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/130681/186471 >> we join A and B column into one: A2:A&B2:B that's why there is arrayformula. with just query the array wont be crated